# which is correct? need help with English

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

which one of two sentences is correct:

> 1: I was once chased by wild dogs!
>
> 2: I have been chased by wild dogs!

Comment: They're both correct, but they mean slightly different things.  Have you looked up the difference between the past simple *was* and the present perfect *have been*?

Comment: @stangdon oh thank you! no I didn’t))gonna check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both correct.

1: I was once chased by wild dogs!

The simple past tense, passive voice.

2: I have been chased by wild dogs!

The present perfect tense, passive voice